# Select the nth row and assign it to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select the nth row and assign it to a variable. So far i have this:

```
  DECLARE @LEVEL INT;   
  DECLARE @COUNT INT = 14;
  DECLARE @A INT = 1;       

    SET @LEVEL = (SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Q_Total) AS rownumber, Q_Response 
    FROM #Qtemp) AS name WHERE rownumber = @COUNT - @A);
```

The select query seems to work but I get this error:

Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 176
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Is what I am doing possible or is there another way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Move the column-aliases to "as name (rownumber, Q_Response)"?

Comment: when you say assign the nth row to a variable do you mean assign a *value* from from n'th row to a variable? In which case change `SELECT * FROM ...` to `SELECT <colname> FROM...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in code. When assigning select result to value it must contain one column in result set. Change to

```
DECLARE @LEVEL INT;   
  DECLARE @COUNT INT = 14;
  DECLARE @A INT = 1;       

    SET @LEVEL = (SELECT  Q_Response FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Q_Total) AS rownumber, Q_Response 
    FROM #Qtemp) AS name WHERE rownumber = @COUNT - @A);
```

If you use SQL 2012 then it may be simplified

```
DECLARE @LEVEL INT;   
DECLARE @COUNT INT = 14;
DECLARE @A INT = 1;       

SELECT @LEVEL = Q_Response FROM  #Qtemp
ORDER BY Q_Total
OFFSET @COUNT - @A ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```